# Azure Automation - Unable to Remove-AzResourceLock

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook, azure-resource-group, azure-resource-lock

I have an issue deleting an Azure Lock, at the resource group level. I am doing it from an Azure Runbook.

I authenticate fine (I am able to *Get* details of whatever I want). Here's the code for that:

```
# Ensures you do not inherit an AzureRMContext in your runbook
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process
"Logging in to Azure..."
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $connection.TenantID -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint
```

And if I do, say, `Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $RG`, I get the info I need. But the problem is that I actually need to delete some resources of that resource group, and it has a lock.

When I `Remove-AzResourceLock -LockId $getAzureLock.LockId -Force`, I am thrown this:

```
Remove-AzResourceLock : AuthorizationFailed : The client XX with object id XX does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/locks/delete' over scope '/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/locks/resourceDellock' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

FYI, I've redacted the subscription/object id information.

For the life of me, I am not able to get around it. The application is added as a Contributor at the subscription level, from Access Control (IAM).

I have tried so many things, that I am just to tired to write down! I am sorry. The last 4 hours I've been reading and trying stuffs. So pardon me!

Please, help me get around this..

Comment: BTW,all this work seamlessly from VSCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [`documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/ManagementLocks/DeleteAtResourceLevel), only `Owner` and `User Access Administrator` built-in roles have the permission to delete a lock and not the `Contributor` role.

> Deletes the management lock of a resource or any level below the
> resource. To delete management locks, you must have access to
> Microsoft.Authorization/* or Microsoft.Authorization/locks/* actions.
> **Of the built-in roles, only Owner and User Access Administrator are
> granted those actions**.

So your solution would be to either grant `Owner`/`User Access Administrator` role to your service principal or create a custom role and grant appropriate permissions on `Microsoft.Authorization/*` actions.

Comment: WHO ARE YOU?

Also, it worked. I changed the role to `User Access Administrator` and it helped. Thank you very much.

Comment: `WHO ARE YOU?` - Santa's Big Helper :D